# Build from scratch SharePoint 2010 Server Guide?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, development, administration, installation

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I'm trying to learn how to setup, maintain and then record how-to videos all based on SharePoint 2010 using Windows Server 2012 R2.  I'm doing this in my own home, so budget is next to nill.  I'll be using trial versions of software but am confused about the actual starting points.  Various articles already assume that many items are in place and don't give a lot of directions.

I'm looking to build a SharePoint 2010 Sever with at least three users connected (admin and regular users). I need all the steps from what to install first and configure and so on.

This is going on a completely blank PC so I need steps that include how to set up the Windows Server as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**You should be aware of the following points before you start.**

- To install SharePoint 2010 with Windows Server 2012 R2 , you will need to download and install [SharePoint 2010 With Service Pack 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=39672) for more details check [SharePoint 2010 support for Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2724471)
- Make sure that the current machine specification match with the [minimum requirement of installing SharePoint 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288751(v=office.14).aspx#section2)

**To install SharePoint 2010 with SP2 on Windows Server 2012**

- Install Windows server 2012 for more details check [Install Windows server 2012 guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2013/03/06/installing-windows-server-2012-step-by-step/)
- [Configure Active Directory](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2012/configuring-active-directory-ad-ds-in-windows-server-2012/) (you can install it on the same machine only for dev environment , but [it's not supported on the production environment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2764086)  ).
- [Create Service Account.](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/01/sharepoint-2013-service-accounts-best-practices-explained.html)
- [Install SQL Server 2008 R2 or 2012](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/31/sql-server-2012-setup/).(SharePoint 2010 is not supported on Microsoft SQL Server 2014)
- Download  [SharePoint 2010 With Service Pack 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=39672) ,
- Make sure that you have an internet connection to can install prerequisites online by clicking on install software Prerequisites .

[image]

- After the prerequisite has been installed successfully ,  Follow the mentioned steps at [Installing SharePoint 2010 – Step by Step](http://mahedee.net/installing-sharepoint-foundation-2010-step-by-step/)
- Now SharePoint should be installed successfully , If you have stopped at any step , tell us on comments.

If you need to install and configure this machine for learning purpose , I suggest to you to start the full guide to [install SharePoint 2010 with Windows Server 2008 R2](http://mosshowto.blogspot.com/2009/11/installing-sharepoint-2010-windows-2008.html)  rather than Windows Server 2012.