# can I install windows sharepoint service 3.0 in windows server 2012?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to install windows SharePoint in windows server 2012. I want to know whether windows SharePoint services 3.0 will suit or just prefer me the best SharePoint version for my windows server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Windows SharePoint services 3.0 is abbreviated to  `WSS` that is the free version for SharePoint 2007 (`MOSS`) .

So you should be aware of the **SharePoint 2007 can't be installed on Windows server 2012** ,

In this case, you can install SharePoint 2010 with Service Pack 2 on Windows server 2012 as I mentioned at [Build from scratch SharePoint 2010 Server Guide?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196016/build-from-scratch-sharepoint-2010-server-guide/196029#196029)

Or install SharePoint 2013 on Windows server 2012,  check the details steps at [install-and-configure-sharepoint-server](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/step-by-step-installation-of-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-server-1)

Answer (score 0):

This May Work:

1. Step 1: Spin up a fresh VM
2. Step 2: Install the roles
3. Step 3: Restart the machine
4. Step 4: Install .netFX 3.5
5. Step 5: Reboot
6. Step 6: Download the installer
7. Step 7: Run the installer
8. Step 8: Install Pre-requisites
9. Step 9: Install SharePoint Foundation 2013
10. Step 10: Pick Standalone
11. Step 11: Reboot
12. Step 12: Ensure services are running.
13. Step 13: Run the config tool
14. Step 14: Reboot the machine
15. Step 15: Install SP1
16. Step 16: Reboot the machine