# Issue Installing SharePoint 2010 Prerequisite "Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64): download error"

Tags: 2010, prerequisites

Hi I am installing SharePoint 2010 Prerequisite on Server 2012. I am getting below error while running setup file for SyncSetup_en.ia64

Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64): download error

Please help

Comment: I found the solution by installing Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime V1.0 SP1 (x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue might occur if you tried to install SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2012 without using **SharePoint 2010 with service pack 2 package**.

So to can install SharePoint 2010 with Windows Server 2012 R2 , you will need to download and install [SharePoint 2010 With Service Pack 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=39672) .

For more details check

- [SharePoint 2010 support for Windows Server 2012 and Windows Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2724471)
- [Build from scratch SharePoint 2010 Server Guide?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196016/build-from-scratch-sharepoint-2010-server-guide/196029#196029)